# How to enable/disable elements depending whether the user is logged in or not?

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In all examples so far I saw examples how to show completely different views -- one for the case when the user is logged in, the other when the user is not logged in.

And I would like to display the same elements, just enable/disable some depending if the user is logged in or not. I though I can go with reading `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and use it like this:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="foobar" 
  IsDisabled="@(!(context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false))">
  ...
</NavLink>
```

But this requires `context`. This property is provided by `AuthorizeView` and this component in turn enforces the aforementioned strict split between two sets of views.

So how to achieve just enable/disable with single common view?

*I am fully aware it is not security measure of any kind.*

**Update** Both answers work with the same effect (thank you once again), but with small caveat -- just right after logging in both methods still returns info user is not authenticated. Here is the follow-up question: [How to get fresh information whether the user is logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805802/how-to-get-fresh-information-whether-the-user-is-logged-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the authentication state data by defining a cascading parameter of type `Task<AuthenticationState>`

Here's a full sample from the docs:

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="LogUsername">Log username</button>

<p>@_authMessage</p>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private string _authMessage;

    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
        }
        else
        {
            _authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The `CascadingAuthenticationState` component is the component that exposes the authentication state to interested parties...

Comment: Many thanks. Just for record, currently this code does not work for me as expected -- after logging in the LoginDisplay component shows I am logged id, shows my name, yet this code claims I am not authenticated. After reloading entire page it states I am -- so both parties are in sync. Now the question is why it cannot see I am logged in, after logging in (I will open another question for it).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `AuthenticationStateProvider` for that. In the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authenticationstateprovider-service) there is an example how to do it.