# Where to set session variables at login to Blazor Server .Net Core 5 site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, session-state

I'm building a Blazor Server .Net Core 5 site and want to look up some values from the database when a user logs in and set them as session variables that I can access from any page. In the default Blazor project, users are directed to "Identity/Account/Login" but that actual page seems to be hidden... otherwise I would think that would be the sensible place to store user variables.

Examples of redirects to the login page:

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

LoginDisplay.razor

```
<a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
```

But there are no such pages:

[Blazor login pages hidden printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebMNe.png)

I've seen there are ways to bring the identity pages into the project so they can be edited, but this is NOT what I want to do. Where is the best place to put my code to look up the data from the database at login and set the session variables so it only runs ONE TIME?

I guess while I'm at it... I'm thinking of setting these session values in a scoped service class in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddScoped<UserSessionService>();
```

Does this make sense for a place to store all user specific session variables or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, based on [How to get fresh information whether the user is logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805802/how-to-get-fresh-information-whether-the-user-is-logged-in).

In my `MainLayout.razor` I have the following code:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject UserService UserService

<MainLayoutHeader/>

<main>
    @Body
</main>

<MainLayoutFooter />

@code {

    private bool authenticated;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Task<AuthenticationState> _currentAuthenticationStateTask;

        AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;

        _currentAuthenticationStateTask = 
            AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

        OnAuthenticationStateChanged(_currentAuthenticationStateTask);
    }

    private void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask)
    {
        _ = InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            var authState = await authenticationStateTask;

            var user = authState.User;

            authenticated = user.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

            Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationStateChanged - {0}", authenticated);

            if (authenticated)
            {       
                await this.UserService.FetchAsync(
                    user);
            }

            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
  }

`UserService` is my service to fetch user info from the API.
```

Comment: Remember to add @implements IDisposable and add provider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= OnAuthenticationStateChanged in Dispose().